# Preprocessing in predictive models

Tags: regression, logistic, predictive-models

I'm trying to make a predictive model using logistic regression but before that I'm wondering what kind of explore I can do on my data to get a better understanding or even help me with the model selection and analysis that follows. I'm thinking of things like tables, plots. What are some good general practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't look at all at the association between the DV and any of the predictors. If you stay ignorant of these relationships before creating models, it's easier to avoid accidentally cheating by using that information to make your models.

Do look at a univariate plot or table of every variable, including the DV. If a predictor has very little variability, leave it out; it can't possibly be much use for prediction. If a variable seems to have a funny distribution or outliers, consider how you might transform it. Avoid histograms, which can deceive you through unlucky bin placement. Use [dot plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_plot_(statistics)) or [density plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_estimation) instead.